# Synchronization of 2 kinds of timestamp

Tags: ros, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node of mine publishes some messages in which their timestamps are according to a dataset read from a file (See Timestamp A below). In the node, there is another subscription of a topic from another node, which uses ROS timestamp (ros::Time::now())(See Timestamp B below).

```
Timestamp A
-----------
678
680
683
685

Timestamp B from ROS
-----------
Output 1 of ros::Time::now()
Output 2 of ros::Time::now()
Output 3 of ros::Time::now()
```

How do I alter/synchronize or map one to another those two kinds of timestamp, because if I want to use *message_filters*, for example, their timestamps should match. The synchronization, I mean, such that Timestamp of 678 in Timestamp A should match Output 1 of ros::Time::now() in Timestamp B, Timestamp of 680 in Timestamp A should match Output 2 of ros::Time::now() in Timestamp B and so on.

EDIT:
My problem is in Timestamp A it's already at 678 seconds say, but in Timestamp B, it's another value comes in(whatever value ros::Time::now() at that moment). I need to process corresponding 2 values with regard to the comparable timestamp of them. How do I match those 2 timestamps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12551/synchronization-of-2-kinds-of-timestamp/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-08**:
It's simply an offline dataset which comprises some data+timestamps(in seconds) there.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-08**:
can you clarify what you mean by "a dataset read from a file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Note that `ros::Time` can be converted to and from `double` seconds. You could do some desired arithmetic using seconds, then convert back to `ros::Time`.

EDIT:

I now suspect you want to play back some previously acquired messages while running another node on the output. This would normally be accomplished by using `rosbag record` to save the messages in a bag file. In that case, this command would play them back with the original times:

```
rosbag play --clock my_saved_messages.bag
```

The [`--clock` option](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play) configures the `ros::Time` interface to use [simulated time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock#A.2BAC8-use_sim_time_parameter).

Since you are not using `rosbag`, you may need to reimplement its simulated time logic. Or, perhaps you can convert your data file to ROS messages and save them using `rosbag`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-08**:
Cont'd: Even, I convert one of them using what you have suggested above, it won't be OK in this case i think. Thanks anyway, to think about this..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-08**:
Cont'd:  For computation in my node, I need to subscribe to that  third-party node's topic and compute with my dataset that all in seconds. The problem now, is that, ros::Time::now() from third party node and mine in seconds.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-08**:
I have a third-party node in which I want to subscribe its topic and the messages published by that topic is using ros::Time::now(). In my own node I have a dataset by which the timestamp is in seconds.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-08**:
Not so clear. On what basis do you wish to match timestamps? Is it just a constant offset between now and time 678? Or, are you asking how to play back data using the original times when they were collected?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-08**:
I've edited my post, hopefully, it's a bit clear for you.